# The Api Url return response on chrome but not Postman

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, http-headers, http-post, postman

I am trying to get currencyies from https://www.ziraatbank.com.tr/tr/fiyatlar-ve-oranlar "Doviz Kurları -> Listele"

[image: This is Chrome General and Response Header picture]

[image: This is Chrome Request Header Picture]

Request URL: https://www.ziraatbank.com.tr/tr/_layouts/15/Ziraat/FaizOranlari/Ajax.aspx/GetDovizKurlari

When I try a POST request to the url from postman, I get a (HTTP 500) error.

The Result headers:

[image: Postman Response Headers]

Request Headers

[image: Postman Request Headers]

What's the cause of my Error?  I couldn't find it. Is it "Cache-Control →private" or a different thing? 
The result is

> {"d":{"Data":"\r\n    \r\n        Döviz Kurları\r\n        \r\n            \r\n
>
> Lütfen fiyatlarını görmek istediğiniz tarihi seçiniz.
>
> \r\n                \r\n                    \r\n                        \r\n                            \r\n                                \r\n                                    \r\n                                    \r\n                                \r\n                            \r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                            Listele\r\n                        \r\n                    \r\n                \r\n                \r\n                    \r\n                        \r\n                            \r\n                        \r\n                        Gişe Kuru\r\n                    \r\n                    \r\n                        \r\n                            \r\n                        \r\n                        İnternet Kuru\r\n                    \r\n                \r\n                \r\n                    \r\n                            \r\n                                \r\n                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                            \r\n                                                Döviz Türü\r\n                                                Döviz Adı\r\n                                                Döviz Alış\r\n                                                Döviz Satış\r\n                                                Efektif Alış\r\n                                                Efektif Satış\r\n                                            \r\n                                        \r\n                                        \r\n                                            \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        USD\r\n                                                        AMERIKAN DOLARI\r\n                                                        6.5787\r\n                                                        6.6582\r\n                                                        6.5721\r\n                                                        6.6582\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        EUR\r\n                                                        EURO\r\n                                                        7.6539\r\n                                                        7.7463\r\n                                                        7.6462\r\n                                                        7.7463\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        GBP\r\n                                                        STERLIN\r\n                                                        8.5001\r\n                                                        8.6027\r\n                                                        8.4916\r\n                                                        8.6027\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        CHF\r\n                                                        ISVIÇRE FRANGI\r\n                                                        6.7841\r\n                                                        6.8661\r\n                                                        6.7502\r\n                                                        6.8661\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        JPY\r\n                                                        100 JAPON YENI\r\n                                                        5.9112\r\n                                                        5.9826\r\n                                                        5.793\r\n                                                        5.9826\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        DKK\r\n                                                        DANIMARKA KRONU\r\n                                                        1.02677\r\n                                                        1.03917\r\n                                                        1.02164\r\n                                                        1.03917\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        SEK\r\n                                                        ISVEÇ KRONU\r\n                                                        0.72325\r\n                                                        0.73199\r\n                                                        0.71963\r\n                                                        0.73199\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        NOK\r\n                                                        NORVEÇ KRONU\r\n                                                        0.78348\r\n                                                        0.79294\r\n                                                        0.77956\r\n                                                        0.79294\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        CAD\r\n                                                        KANADA DOLARI\r\n                                                        4.9926\r\n                                                        5.0528\r\n                                                        4.9676\r\n                                                        5.0528\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        AUD\r\n                                                        AVUSTRALYA DOLARI\r\n                                                        4.72579\r\n                                                        4.78285\r\n                                                        4.70216\r\n                                                        4.78285\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        SAR\r\n                                                        S.ARABISTAN RIYAL\r\n                                                        1.75405\r\n                                                        1.77523\r\n                                                        1.70143\r\n                                                        1.77523\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        RUB\r\n                                                        RUS RUBLESİ\r\n                                                        0.09636\r\n                                                        0.09772\r\n                                                        0.09173\r\n                                                        0.09772\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                        \r\n                                    \r\n                                \r\n                            \r\n                            \r\n                                \r\n                                    \r\n                                        \r\n                                            \r\n                                                Döviz Türü\r\n                                                Döviz Adı\r\n                                                Döviz Alış\r\n                                                Döviz Satış\r\n                                                Efektif Alış\r\n                                                Efektif Satış\r\n                                            \r\n                                        \r\n                                        \r\n                                            \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        GBP\r\n                                                        STERLIN\r\n                                                        8.5065\r\n                                                        8.5962\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        CHF\r\n                                                        ISVIÇRE FRANGI\r\n                                                        6.7892\r\n                                                        6.861\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        JPY\r\n                                                        100 JAPON YENI\r\n                                                        5.9156\r\n                                                        5.9781\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        DKK\r\n                                                        DANIMARKA KRONU\r\n                                                        1.02754\r\n                                                        1.03839\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        SEK\r\n                                                        ISVEÇ KRONU\r\n                                                        0.72379\r\n                                                        0.73144\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        NOK\r\n                                                        NORVEÇ KRONU\r\n                                                        0.78407\r\n                                                        0.79235\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        CAD\r\n                                                        KANADA DOLARI\r\n                                                        4.9963\r\n                                                        5.049\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        AUD\r\n                                                        AVUSTRALYA DOLARI\r\n                                                        4.72933\r\n                                                        4.77926\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        USD\r\n                                                        AMERIKAN DOLARI\r\n                                                        6.5836\r\n                                                        6.6532\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                                    \r\n                                                        EUR\r\n                                                        EURO\r\n                                                        7.6596\r\n                                                        7.7405\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                        0\r\n                                                    \r\n                                                \r\n                                        \r\n                                    \r\n                                \r\n                            \r\n                        \r\n                \r\n

Comment: Are you using that URL for a reason? What are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: Yes. I am expecting result like on the post. I edited againg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. I forget add body into request .
 Headers

```
application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Body

```
{date: "2018-09-06"}
```